# Facing issue regarding installation in hybris6.6

Tags: installation, sap-commerce-cloud

While installing the hybris, my localextension.xml is creating in comment form. I am very new in hybris ecommerce development.

So I have followed below steps for installing the hyrbis -

> Installed the zip version of Hybris 6.6 
>   Unzip it
>   From Platform folder, I opened the terminal and ran ". ./setantenv.sh" And after that I ran "**ant clean all**" and after the build completed succesfully all folders got created in Hybris folder.
>   Then I ran "**./hybrisserver.sh**" and my server got started successfully.
>   Then I ran "https://localhost:9002/" over that I initialize and it also went successfully.
>   When I try to access hmc or backoffice it is giving me **404 page not found error**. 
>   I checked my **localextension.xml** file and found all the extensions generated as a comment as shown below.

Could anyone help me out where I am doing the mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using original package you need to install a receipt. Go to install folder.
Run below command for listing existing receipt

```
./install.sh -l
```

Prepare b2c with acc:

```
./install.sh -r b2c_acc
```

Initialize b2c with acc (Also you can use **ant clean all** for this step):

```
./install.sh -r b2c_acc initialize
```

Start hybris (Also you can use **./hybrisserver.sh start** for this step):

```
./install.sh -r b2c_acc start
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do "ant all" for the first time and set-up the config folder, it generates a localextensions.xml file which contains extensions that are commented out. If you initialize and start Hybris using this setting, you get nothing, except the HAC.

To enable HMC, you need to at least have "platformhmc" extension enabled (i.e. not commented out) in localextensions. So, stop Hybris, uncomment platformhmc, and do another build (i.e. "ant all"). After that, you can do a Platform Update, or a Platform Initialize (to build from scratch again). When it's done, and you've started Hybris, HMC should be accessible.

Or, if you want more features enabled by default, you can do @mkysoft's suggestion and use recipes.

Comment: If any of the solutions helped, please don't forget to Upvote / Accept the answers / suggestions.